# How can I write a paragraph on the right side of a page?

Tags: paragraphs, books

I'm using `\documentclass{book}`and I hope I can write a paragraph on the right side of the page.

So any help please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, clarify the question. What do yo mean with writing a paragraph on the right side of a page (writing the paragraph in the margin, flush right, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify if the "right corner" is that of the whole page, only the top right margin, only the right of the top lines in the text area or perhaps the corner of the  header ... but anyway, it should work fix a box with some absolute position using the `textpos` package. Change as you need:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{textblock}{6}(9,.5)
\lipsum[2]
\end{textblock}
\vspace*{4em}
\lipsum[3-6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want paragraphs to be aligned to the right side, you can use `\raggedleft` to achieve this.

If you want to place a paragraph in the margin, you can use the `\marginpar` command.

For the first case,

```
Here is my normal text.\par
{\raggedleft Here is the text I want aligned right.\par}
Here is more normal text.
```

For the second case,

```
Here is my normal paragraph text.\marginpar{This text will appear in the right margin,
next to my normal paragraph.} Here is more normal paragraph text.
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is a problem when I tried it. 
Half of the paragraph is cut when I used _marginbar_ so is there a way to prevent indent right before the margin end by enough space.